# Delay a Job Start Date

Tags: start-date

When I got the job offer and signed the contract, they gave me a start date but they also gave me an earlier date. Just in case the slots aren't full, they'll put me on that date. I was fine with it since it's still 2 weeks away at that time. But I got sick for a week and got stuck on one of the pre-employment requirements. I immediately wrote a request letter to put me on the original start date but they don't have a specific email for their company and I arrived into the post office late, and the next day is a weekend. And the job starts on Monday night.

Do I just drop off the letter at the site as early as possible?
Am I doing the right thing?

Is my employment in any danger? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> Do I just drop off the letter at the site as early as possible? Am I
>   doing the right thing?

No.

Go to the place of employment with your letter in hand, and talk to someone in person (HR, the hiring manager, etc). Explain what happened, when you would like to start, and ask what you should do now. It's possible that some of the pre-employment requirements can be fulfilled while you are working and won't actually delay your start date.

If they only need the letter, then give it to them. If there is other paperwork to be filled out, then do so.

And ask for contact phone numbers and emails.

> Is my employment in any danger?

Probably not. But avoiding the possibility that letters will get lost will improve your chances.

Comment: Or simply phone and talk to someone in HR